# Delete old files from ftp using shell script

Tags: shell, ftp

I want a script that remove old files from FTP server, but nothing works.
I tested the following script that i found, but when i run, i receive the error: "syntax error in expression (error token is "0+5")".

Someone can help me?

```html
#!/bin/bash
# get a list of files and dates from ftp and remove files older than ndays
ftpsite="HOSTNAME" 
ftpuser="USERNAME" 
ftppass="PASSWORD" 
putdir="FOLDER" 

#age of files they should delete
ndays=1

# work out our cutoff date
MM=`date --date="$ndays days ago" +%b`
DD=`date --date="$ndays days ago" +%d`

echo removing files older than $MM $DD

# get directory listing from remote source
listing=`ftp -i -n $ftpsite <<EOMYF 
user $ftpuser $ftppass
binary
cd $putdir
ls
quit
EOMYF
`
lista=( $listing )

# loop over our files
for ((FNO=0; FNO<${#lista[@]}; FNO+=9));do
  # month (element 5), day (element 6) and filename (element 8)
  #echo Date ${lista[`expr $FNO+5`]} ${lista[`expr $FNO+6`]}          File: ${lista[`expr $FNO+8`]}

  # check the date stamp
  if [ ${lista[`expr $FNO+5`]}=$MM ];
  then
    if [[ ${lista[`expr $FNO+6`]} -lt $DD ]];
    then
      # Remove this file
      echo "Removing ${lista[`expr $FNO+8`]}" 
      ftp -i -n $ftpsite <<EOMYF2 
      user $ftpuser $ftppass
      binary
      cd $putdir
      delete ${lista[`expr $FNO+8`]}
      quit
EOMYF2

    fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `expr $FNO+5` with `expr $FNO + 5` and `expr $FNO+6` with `expr $FNO + 6`

OR

you can use the newer `bash|ksh|zsh` feature like

```
 if [[ ${lista[$((FNO+5))]} == "$MM" ]]; then
```

Very lightly tested. Note that something that evaluates to `"3" == "03"` will be false.

The `$(( math cmd sub cmds ))` construct can use most C lang math operators like `++`  ( and many others that I don't use much, so `man bash|ksh|zsh` to get the details.).

Note that you don't need to use `$FNO`, but plain `FNO` will be evaluated as `$FNO`.

Of course, you'll need to fix `$FNO+6` and `$FNO+8` as well.

IHTH.

Comment: I used "if [[ ${lista[$((FNO+5))]} == "$MM" ]];" and work! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Glad that helped! if you found my answer was useful for you, you can 'accept' it by clicking on the arrow, by the up-down arrows surround the number at the top left of my answer. Good code other wise for managing ftp deletions. Good luck.

Comment: @JhonatanSilva I tried this script. Its running without any error but not deleting files. Can you please mail me its copy to 106597@gmail.com?

Comment: use `set -x` to see the variable values that are eXpanded when you run the script. There is probably an assumption on your part that is different than assumptions of Jhonatan. Good luck.